# What is the name of Control equipment?

Tags: safety, flight-controls, control-surfaces

I wanted to know the name of equipment that controls the control surfaces of an aircraft by taking commands from the pilot through it's hotas stick. The aircraft could be a combat 50's or 60's a/c, so possibly there would be a specific name of such control equipment.

Will this equipment be the most safety critical equipment in such an aircraft compared to other equipment such as NAU (Navigation and Attack unit) or will there be any other more safety critical equipment in an a/c?

Edit: Let the a/c be a Mirage.

Comment: "HOTAS" is a concept of a functional stick (with buttons controlling equipment), it is not a universal name.

Comment: let the a/c be a mirage.

Comment: 50s-60s aircraft were not HOTAS. Every pair of surfaces had its own linkages to the appropriate control or stick axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aircraft like that would have used mechanical connections between the stick and the control surfaces.  Either cables, or push-pull rods.  According to [this](https://www.dassault-aviation.com/en/passion/aircraft/military-dassault-aircraft/mirage-iii/) the Mirage III used "servo controls", which likely would have been hydraulic boost to the mechanical linkages.

Answer (score 1):

Most aircraft of that era used hydraulic systems to actuate the flight control surfaces.  And yes, controlling the aircraft is critical to flight safety.